# Problem with std::uniform_real_distribution<T> and std::numeric_limits<T>::max() for T == long double under Valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have problem with following code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

int main() {
  using T = long double;
  std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device{}() };
  const auto max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
  const auto res = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>(0., max)(engine);
  assert(res < max);
}
```

This code executes properly as a standalone program. Unfortunately, under Valgrind the assertion is unsatisfied. The problem occurs only for `T == long double`, i.e. `double` and `float` cases are not problematic.

Can you explain the nature of the problem?

(I work with GCC 9.3.0 and Valgrind 3.15.0 on GNU/Linux x86_64. I used *-O0 -g* flags for GCC and *--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --errors-for-leak-kinds=all --run-cxx-freeres=yes* for Valgrind.)

Comment: Even `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is different under Valgrind: `0xf.fffffffffffffffp+16380` vs `0x8p+16381`. Valgrind [doesn't](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html) fully support `long double`s: *There is no support for 80 bit arithmetic. Internally, Valgrind represents all such "long double" numbers in 64 bits...*

Comment: @Evg sounds like an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that Valgrind doesn't fully support `long double`. The manual [reads](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html):

> Valgrind has the following limitations in its implementation of x86/AMD64 floating point relative to IEEE754.
>
> There is no support for 80 bit arithmetic. Internally, Valgrind represents all such "long double" numbers in 64 bits, and so there may be some differences in results. ...

Consider this simple code:

```
int main() {
  auto max = static_cast<long double>(std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
  std::cout << std::hexfloat << max << std::endl;
}
```

The output is the same if run standalone and under Valgrind:

```
0xf.ffffffffffff8p+1020
```

Now let's try to print the next representable value by adding the line

```
max = std::nextafter(max, std::numeric_limits<long double>::max());
```

We get the expected output without Valgrind, but different output under Valgrind:

```
0xf.ffffffffffff801p+1020    // no Valgrind
0xf.ffffffffffff8p+1020      // under Valgrind
```

Similar inconsistency is observed if we try to print `std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()` value itself:

```
0xf.fffffffffffffffp+16380   // no Valgrind
0x8p+16381                   // under Valgrind
```

No wonder that `std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>` fails, in some implementation-dependent way, with `std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()`.

Comment: I just happened to hit this myself, where `numeric_limits<long double>::max() == numeric_limits<long double>::inf()` under valgrind. Thanks for the hex dumps!

Comment: Correction: the two don't compare as equal under valgrind, but `std::isinf(numeric_limits<long double>::max())`  is true.